# Google Voice "Call With..."

Tags: calls, nexus-7, google-voice

I love the Call With... feature in the Google Voice [webapp](http://www.google.com/voice) and use it often. It allows you to initiate a call from your Google Voice number by first dialing one of your linked phones then patching you through to the number you want to dial:

[image: Google Voice Webapp Call With...]

This would be perfect for my Nexus 7 - I'm often at home on my couch next to my land line phone wanting to make a call. I don't want a VOIP solution for the tablet, I'd rather tell GV to call my land line and patch me through to the number I want to dial (the call quality is much better on the land line). I can't find this feature in the Google Voice [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice&hl=en). I've used the webapp, via Chrome, on the N7 but that's kind of clunky. Does anyone know of more finger-friendly way to initiate a GV call like this from an Android device?

Comment: Having GV on your landline's speed dial seems like it would be easiest ... though I can see that making use of your device's contacts could simplify things too.  Seems like you need a smartphone landline :P

Comment: You're using a tablet. Why not just use the regular web interface?

Answer (score 1):

There's an app I used to use specifically for this. It's called [Voice+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.xilard.voiceplus). You dial a number, it asks you which of your google voice connected numbers to call.

However, this app catches the `intent` from when you dial a phone number. The Nexus 7 doesn't have the Phone app installed. You could try installing another dialer app like [Go Contacts Ex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbapps.contactpro) and see if dialing a number from their interface brings up Voice+.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the regular web interface was too heavy, so I created GoogleVoiceCallingPageLite (GVCPL):
"A Lightweight HTML page for making and receiving Google Voice calls" . You can find it at https://sourceforge.net/projects/googlevoicecallingpagelite/.  I created it to use on my computer, not a phone/tablet, but if you want you can use it on your phone/tablet too, just by going to http://www.elvey.com/GVCPL.html.  It's the exact same code as on sourceforge, where you can see a screenshot too.

As noted there: To use: Log in, then open this page. It only works if you're already logged in, otherwise, it doesn't work - and doesn't (yet) give a useful error message.