# Click2Call with Google Voice on Android

Tags: google-voice, default-applications

I have an HSPA+ Galaxy Nexus (Google Nexus 3) with T-Mobile USA online-and-walmart-exclusive 30$/mo 5GB@4G unlimited data plan, and I was disappointed to find out that I cannot use the official Google Voice app to perform `Click2Call` and make calls by receiving `SIP` `INVITE`'s through an *IPKall* DDI number tied to an `Internet Call` `Account` within the official/default `Phone` app.

Why the `Click2Call` feature is available only in the iOS version of Google Voice, and is missing from Android?

How can I make Click2Call work without having to use any third-party apps or solutions with unclear security clearances?

I thought I could easily create an icon-app from https://www.google.com/voice/m, similarly to how it's done from Safari on iOS with the `Add to Home Screen` option, but I didn't find any similar options when visiting the web-app in the default `Browser` app on Android.

Comment: If I understand correctly, sounds like this is related to (but not a duplicate of) what I was looking for when asking a [recent question of mine](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35238/11343).

Comment: Absolutely!  So far, both questions can be solved by switching to iPhone/iPad/etc and the official Google Voice app on iOS.  Somehow the Click2Call feature has been on iOS GV for a really long time, but is still missing from the Android version!